# Restrict acces to file field only to certain role

Tags: 7, users

I have a node-type called "download" that has a field "file" with unlimited entries. Those files are already stored inside a private path. Now I want to restrict access only to a certain role. I already tried [field_permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) but when I enable `View field_file, regardless of content author.` and grant that permission only to authenticated users, I still can view/download that file as a guest. What am I doing wrong here?

Besides it would be nice to set permissions on a node base. Like "This Node is only Viewable by Role XYZ".

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like Colin McClure says, to control per node you can use with http://drupal.org/project/content_access .In the respective Access Control tab of each Content Type (when you edit a content type), you will find, in the bottom, the option to enable per content node access control settings.

About control per fields, seems that exist several modules to achive this:

- http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions
- http://drupal.org/project/cck_private_fields
- http://drupal.org/project/privacy

and, from [this resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336629/set-cck-field-permissions-per-php-in-drupal-6) you can find hooks to get permissions per field:

http://drupalcode.org/project/cck.git/blob/refs/heads/6.x-3.x:/modules/content_permissions/content_permissions.module

```
<?php

/**
 *  Implementation of hook_perm().
 */
function content_permissions_perm() {
  $perms = array();
  foreach (content_fields() as $field) {
    $perms[] = 'edit '. $field['field_name'];
    $perms[] = 'view '. $field['field_name'];
  }
  return $perms;
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_field_access().
 *
 * @see content_access().
 */
function content_permissions_field_access($op, $field, $account, $node = NULL) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'view':
    case 'edit':
      return user_access($op .' '. $field['field_name'], $account);
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Nice, that solves at least the "on a node base"-permission-problem.  ^^ Stil can view the files attached to that node which i do not have access to, though in private folder.

Comment: If I understand well, this indication could be useful http://drupal.org/node/1175654

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to set permissions on a node basis then you need another module called [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access). Do bear in mind though that the more ACL permissions you use the slower the site will become. Unfortunately, this is a side effect.

Comment: Nice Module. Yet this does not solve my main-problem with the images. I still can view images which i should not have access to.

Answer (score 0):

For the actual download ability, you can try https://www.drupal.org/project/private_files_download_permission.

> ...a simple permission to allow downloading of private files by role...